# UITableView jumps to top showing SearchBar when "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" is true for segue from Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I encountered an issue which I can't explain to myself and I hope that you can point me in the right direction or even provide me suitable solution.

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController with a custom prototype UITableViewCell. In my Storyboard, I added a Segue to show (push) a detail view controller onto the stack. This works fine and nothing is unexpected so far.

However, when I press the back button on my detail view controller, it goes back to my UITableViewController but this time, the TableView jumps to the top and reveals the TableViews HeaderView in which I put a SearchBar.

This happens when I check the "**Hide Bottom Bar on Push**" on my **detail view controller**, which I need so that the detail view controller hides the tab bar from the UITabBarController in which I embedded the NavigationController.

My hierarchy looks something like this:

```
-UITabBarController
--UINavigationController
---UITableViewController (my table view controller)
--(more view controllers for other tabs)
```

The strange thing is that this does not happen immediately. When I go back, at first everything looks good but then after a very short time it really jumps to the very top of the tableview.

I logged the table views contentOffset and its like this after I press the back button:

```
T0.000: viewDidLayoutSubviews => -20 
T0.011: viewWillAppear => 44
T0.023: viewDidLayoutSubviews => -20 
T0.530: viewDidAppear => -20 (correct value, same as before the push)
T0.540: viewDidLayoutSubviews => -64 (wrong value, showing search bar)
```

What does happen after round about half a second? Why does it suddently jumps to the top? I never set the offset by myself. It is somehow done automatically by the system and if I uncheck the "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" in my detail view controller, the behaviour is working as expected meaning if I had the search bar visible before, it is visible after and if it was hidden before, its still hidden after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couln't find out how to fix this but at least I found a workaround to stop the jumping. I observed the same issue in other apps and even apple doesn't hide the search bar on app start anymore. Maybe because of this issue, who knows? So here is my solution.

First, this issue only happens if your table view has less cells than it would need to fill the whole screen. As soon as you have more cells than can fit on screen, after going to the detail view and then back to the master view, the tableview does not jump and stays at the very same position.

With this knowledge, I was able to create a workaround. My workaround is rather simple. I use segues to show various parts of my app so in my UITableViewController which is the "master", in prepare(for segue:sender:), before I show the detail view, I check if the first cell of the table view is visible. If so, I scroll the tableview to show the search bar.

```
if let firstCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) {
    if tableView.visibleCells.contains(firstCell) && !searchController.isActive {
        let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top)
        tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When clicking one of the cells, a segue to show the details of the entry is performed. If the first cell is visible, i scroll the tableview down a little bit to show the search bar.

A better approach might be to actually calculate how many cells can fit on the screen and how many cells we have in total so we really only show the search bar when there are not enough cells but I found that this solution is good enough for me since it prevents jumping.